# Determine if a file is an icon

Tags: c#

I'm reading from an image file via `OpenImageFileDialog`, which accepts both `.ico` and bitmap file. With icons, I need to create an `Icon` object and convert it to a bitmap.

How can I tell whether a file is actually an icon? Just checking for an `.ico` extension seems unreliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I haven't seen many Bitmaps that disguised as `.ico` and vice versa. Using the extension to determine such things is actually the most common way.

If you want to be clever you can try opening an image as Bitmap, and if that fails try if it's an icon, and if that fails give up.

This kind of cleverness quickly becomes a pain, however, if the number of formats you support increases. You can try peeking into the file and determining the file format from the header in that case which might be fater than letting a parser fail (also it avoids exception-driven programming).

Comment: I agree. If file extensions are wrong that is the fault of the file system, doesn't mean you should be able to read it. Many older apps just wouldn't work with the wrong extension, they didn't even attempt to read it.

Comment: I agree, parsing the file for type verification seems like the secured way.